# Как установить zend-developer-tools?

Tags: php, composer, zend2

Установил через композер Zend framework, установить zend-developer-tools через композер не удалось, получаю ошибку:

$ php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-developer-tools 1.2.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-developer-tools[1.2.0].
    - Conclusion: remove zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - zendframework/zend-developer-tools 1.2.0 requires zendframework/zend-view ^2.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-view[2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.6.6, 2.6.7, 2.6.8, 2.7.0, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1].
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.10.0|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.10.1|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.11.0|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.11.1|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.6.0|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.6.1|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.6.2|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.6.3|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.6.4|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.6.5|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.6.6|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.6.7|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.6.8|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.7.0|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.8.0|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.8.1|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.8.2|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.9.0|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-view 2.9.1|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - Installation request for zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.3.0].

Файл композера:

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "1.2.0"

    }
}
```

Кто может помочь установить?:)

Answer (score 0):

Убрать эту строку из composer.json

Произвести обновление сначала с помощью `composer update`

Потом `composer require zendframework/zend-developer-tools`

Мне подобное помогло.

Comment: Николай, какую «эту строку» Вы имели в виду? Спасибо.